# selected values in one should not appear in the other two drop downs : Select2 - multiple drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

> There are three drop downs using 'select2 - multi select '  , and need to link three of them , the selected values in one should not appear in the other two. when the option is  removed it should show up as an option available for selection.

initially one drop down is visible, the other two are created dynamically when clicking the add button

**Issue :**  duplication of unselected values -  selected values are not shown in the second dropdown, but the unselected values are shown twice .

> values are fetched from db to fill the first drop down.

**Codeigniter VIEW :**
This hidden field is used to fetch 'masterOptionValue' using java-script :

```
    <div class="col-md-4" style="display: none;">
    <label style="display: none;" class="control-label" for="group">parent group</label>
    <?php
    $options = array();
    foreach ($groups as $group):
    {
        $i=$group['id'];
        $options[$i] = $group['group_name'];
    }
    endforeach;
    $selected_option = set_value('group');
    if(!$selected_option)
        $selected_option = '';
    $js=' style="display:none;" multiple data-plugin-selectTwo id="group" name="group" class="form-control populate immune" required tabindex=2';
    ?>

    <?php echo form_dropdown('group',$options,$selected_option,$js); ?>

</div>
```

The first visible dropdown, the other two dropdowns are added dynamically when the plus button is clicked.

```
<div class="col-md-4">

    <label class="" for="group"> Group</label>
    <?php
    $options = array();
    foreach ($groups as $group):
    {
        $i=$group['id'];
        $options[$i] = $group['group_name'];
    }
    endforeach;
    $selected_option = set_value('group');
    if(!$selected_option)
        $selected_option = '';
    $js='multiple data-plugin-selectTwo id="group" name="group" class="form-control input-sm slave group11" required tabindex=2';
    ?>

    <?php echo form_dropdown('group',$options,$selected_option,$js); ?>

</div>
```

Here is screenshot of the second dropdown with duplicated option values, only the selected value "group2" in the first dropdown is not shown in the second one. All other values are shown twice.

[image]

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on("change", ".slave", function(){
        PopulateAllDropDowns();
    });


function PopulateAllDropDowns()
{
    // populate all the slave drop downs
    $('select.slave ').each(function(index){
    console.log('attr-id: '+$(this).attr('id'));
    PopulateDropDown($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}



function PopulateDropDown(id)
    {
        // preserve the selected value
        var selectedValue = $('#'+id).val();

        // clear current contents
        $('#'+id).html('');

        // attempt to add each option from the master drop down
        $('select#group').children('option').each(function(index){

            // scope-safe var
            var masterOptionValue = $(this).val();
                //console.log('master drop down values : '+masterOptionValue);
            // check if option is in use in another slave drop down, unless it's immune
            var optionInUse = false;
            if (!$(this).hasClass("immune"))
            {
                $('select.slave option:selected').each(function(index){
                    if (masterOptionValue == $(this).val() )
                        optionInUse = true;
                        //console.log('option in use :'+masterOptionValue+' : '+optionInUse );
                });

            }

            // if it's not in use, add it to this slave drop down
            if (!optionInUse)
            {
                // create new option
                var newOption = $('<option></option>').val($(this).val()).html($(this).text());
                    console.log(newOption);
                // ensure selected value is preserved, if applicable
                if (selectedValue == $(this).val())
                    newOption.attr('selected', 'selected');

                // add the option
                $('#'+id).append(newOption);
            }

        });
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I know the logic is having error, please let me  know .

Comment: can its possible for you to create a jsfiddle/running code snippet for this with hard coded option values for master drop down.

Comment: Not really sure. you have both dropdowns populating same php values? how you expect them to be different